# Check if names of a list are member of a list of names

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to compare two star catalogs, the problem is that the names of stars are different in each catalog. For comparision, I have a third catalog with common names of each star. So I need to crosscheck two lists with a third and create a fourth containing all star properties. Im summary, consider the following catalogs:

```
hypatia={"HIP87382", "2MASS19290895+4311502", "HIP98314", "HIP98316", "HIP106931",...}
names={{"2259072226846681494447849441045193405", "HIP87382", "HD162826", 
  "BD+4003225B+4003225", "2MASS17511402+4004208", 
  "GaiaDR21344497769227698432", "TYC3093-01946-1", "HR06669", 
  "GaiaDR11344497764930721536"},...}
```

I need to create a list where each entry correspond to a list `{i,j}`, `i` beeing the position of name `hypatia[[j]]` in `names` list. I tried the following brute force method:

```
indhyp={}
Do[
 If[MemberQ[names[[i]], hypatia[[j]]], 
  indhyp = Append[indhyp, {i, j}]],
 {i, 1, Length[names]}, {j, 1, Length[hypatia]}
 ]
```

The problem is that this code returns the following:

```
{{1, 1612}, {1, 1613}, {4, 725}, {4, 726}, {4, 727}, {5, 1042},...}
```

As can be seen, the first two terms are repeated, meaning that both `hypatia[[1612]]` and `hypatia[[1613]]` appears in the position `names[[1]]`. That's wrong, as `hypatia[[1612]]` and `hypatia[[1613]]` are different stars with different names.
I have no clue why.
Is there any other non brute force method, or any clue why this problem is happening?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: Consider `poslist = Position[names, #] & /@ hypatia`. This should give you a list of singletons, each containing the desired position specification; check that that's the case with `MatchQ[poslist, {{{___}}...}]`. If you get `True`, then you can safely take the first (and only) element of each: `poslist = First /@ poslist` But if you get `False`, let me know...

Comment: and just to be clear, we have both `MatchQ[names, {{___String}...}]` and `MatchQ[hypatia, {___String}]`, right?

Comment: also: do you have some broader task you want to *do* with this resulting list of parts? there may be an easier way to cross-check them in mathematica...!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your description correctly. You have a list with names in "hypatia". Then the same names appear in a list of lists named "names". And you want determine the indices of names from "hypatia" in the list of lists "names". The command "Position" will do the job. Here is an example:

For an example we create names from numbers:

```
hypatia = Table[ToString[i], {i, 100}];
```

We then split these names into a list of lists:

```
names = Partition[hypatia, 10];
```

You could additonally add names that do not appear in "hypatia", but for simplicity I am not doing this. Now `Position will give you the indices:

```
Flatten[Position[names, #]] & /@ hypatia
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
hypatia = {"HIP87382", "2MASS19290895+4311502", "HIP98314", "HIP98316", "HIP106931"};
```

A random list of names:

```
SeedRandom[1]

names = Table[RandomSample[#, 5] & @
    Union[{"2259072226846681494447849441045193405", "HIP87382", 
      "HD162826", "BD+4003225B+4003225", "2MASS17511402+4004208", 
      "GaiaDR21344497769227698432", "TYC3093-01946-1", "HR06669", 
      "GaiaDR11344497764930721536"}, hypatia], 10];

Column @ names
```

[image]

**1.** Using [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
poslist = Join @@ Outer[
   If[MemberQ[names[[#]], hypatia[[#2]]], {#, #2}, Nothing] &, 
   Range @ Length @ names, Range @ Length @ hypatia]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {7, 2},
>  {8,  3}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}}
> ```

**2.** Using [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
posF = If[MemberQ[names[[#]], hypatia[[#2]]], {#, #2}, Nothing] &;

poslist2 = posF @@@ Tuples[{Range @ Length @ names, Range @ Length @ hypatia}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {7, 2},
>   {8, 3}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}}
> ```

**3.** Using [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) + [`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html):

```
poslist3 = Join @@ MapIndexed[Join @@ 
  (Thread[{#2[[1]], PositionIndex[hypatia]@#}] /. {_, _Missing} :> Nothing) &, 
   names, {2}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {7, 2}, 
>   {8, 3}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}}
> ```